# persistentDatapath is not allowed called from Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: error.]

I also try putting it on start and awake like what the error said but all i got is more error instead.

```
public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
      private string SavePath = $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/save.text";

    public void Save()
    {
        var state = LoadFile();
        CaptureState(state);
        SaveFile(state);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        var state = LoadFile();
        RestoreState(state);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> LoadFile()
    {
        if(!File.Exists(SavePath))
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }
        using(FileStream stream = File.Open(SavePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return(Dictionary<string, object>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }


    private void SaveFile(object state)
    {
        using(var stream = File.Open(SavePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, state);
        }
    }

    private void CaptureState(Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        foreach(var saveable in FindObjectsOfType<Entity>())
        {
            state[saveable.Id] = saveable.CaptureState();
        }
    }

    private void RestoreState(Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        foreach(var saveable in FindObjectsOfType<Entity>())
        {
            if(state.TryGetValue(saveable.Id, out object value))
            {
                saveable.RestoreState(value);
            }
        }
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Try initializing SavePath in Awake or Start rather than in the field initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well exactly as the error suggests rather do

```
private string SavePath;

private void Awake ()
{
    SavePath = $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/save.text";
}
```

In general rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which uses the correct path separator depending on the platform

```
SavePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "save.text");
```

Or you could also make it a property but this returns a new string everytime

```
private string SavePath => Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "save.text");
```